# Simple regex to remove a tag from a document

Tags: regex, vbscript, wsh

Having some trouble with a very simple regex to remove a tag from a document, can you help me figure out why it won't work?  Basically, what I want to match is any portion of the text in the entire string that starts with "<Schema>" and ends with </Schema>.  there will be a lot of stuff between the tags that want taken out.  Using the ^ and $ I should be able to grab the string and replace it.

this is working, but only if I don't have any other characters at the start or end of the string.  Here is my code, this first case works:

```
Dim strPayload
Dim fso, f1
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f1 = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Prsxfer\Upload\Regex\upload" & year(now()) & right("0" & month(now()), 2) & right("0" & day(now()), 2) & ".xml")
Dim objRegEx
strPayload = "<Schema blah blah> </Schema>"

Set objRegEx  = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Global = True   
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "^<Schema.*</Schema>$"
strPayload = objRegEx.Replace(strPayload, "replaced")

f1.writeline strPayload

f1.close
set f1 = Nothing
set headerFile = Nothing
set fso = Nothing
```

outputs: "replaced" correct.

however, if I have anything before or after the thing i'm trying to find, then it no longer does the replacement.  so replacing line 6 with any of:

```
strPayload = "a<Schema blah blah> </Schema>"
```

or

```
strPayload = "<Schema blah blah> </Schema>a"
```

or

```
strPayload = "a<Schema blah blah> </Schema>a"
```

will not match, i'll just get back my original string I sent in.

How do I need to modify the regex to work with leading and trailing information?

btw, I am using vbscript.

*edit, the complete input actually looks more like this.  while the solution below works if it's on one line, it doesn't seem to work if the tag is across multiple lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <GRS_MESSAGES>
    <RESPONSE_FORMAT_CODE>XML</RESPONSE_FORMAT_CODE>
    <RESPONSE_CONTENT_CODE>FAIL</RESPONSE_CONTENT_CODE>
    <Schema name="Schema1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
      <ElementType name="C" content="empty" model="closed">
        <AttributeType name="Tag" dt:type="i4"/>
        ...
      </ElementType>
    </Schema>
  </GRS_MESSAGES>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will sort of work, but only if Schema can't be nested within itself.

`objRegEx.Pattern = "<Schema.*?</Schema>"`

So it will fail on `<schema>stuff<schema>stuff</schema>stuff</schema>` as it will become `replacedstuff</schema>`.

Comment: that works!  i'm not worried about nested schemas, that will not happen.

technically, you've answered the question, so I will give you the point for it.  However, this is still not working in my implementation, it's not finding the text to replace.  I'm thinking maybe because it's multiline.  I'll paste part of the xml here in next comment..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GRS_MESSAGES>
      <RESPONSE_FORMAT_CODE>XML</RESPONSE_FORMAT_CODE>
      <RESPONSE_CONTENT_CODE>FAIL</RESPONSE_CONTENT_CODE>
      <Schema name="Schema1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
        <ElementType name="C" content="empty" model="closed">
          <AttributeType name="Tag" dt:type="i4"/>
          ...
        </ElementType>
      </Schema>
    </GRS_MESSAGES>

sorry formatting doesn't translate well in comments

Comment: Try adding `objRegEx.Multiline=True`.  It is undocumented, but it does what you need it to do.  VBScript's Regex library is really bad.

Comment: I did try that, it still won't find it though.  I edited the original question to show a better representation of the actual input.

Comment: Ah, I guess they only partially implemented multiline.  Sorry, I've never had to use it.  You might need to skip regex and just do the search in the string yourself (Instr) if that is what you are looking to do, or look to using the XML parser which is probably an even better idea.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking i could just find the position of the start of schema, and the end of schema, and then use mid to remove it.  seemed like regex was a better way to go.  unfortunately can't insert xmlparser into this process.  giving you the point anyway though because technically you did solve the original problem, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take my shot at it here. Should give you a global tag match with the text in the middle of tags as the capture group. If you weren't looking for a capture group remove the parenthesis around the `.*` in the middle (as shown below).

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "<.*>?(.*)</.*>"
```

or

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "<.*>?.*</.*>"
```

I tested it against the replacement examples for line 6 that you gave, and it hits a match each time. Please let me know if this works for you!

Comment: it looks like this would search for any tag start and end?  what I need is only &lt;Schema and &gt;/Schema&gt;

so I assume the fix would be to write it like this:
objRegEx.Pattern = "<Schema?.*<Schema/>"

similar to the first answer, except position of the ? is before the dot in yours instead of after the *.  In this case, the pattern
    objRegEx.Pattern = "<Schema.*?</Schema>"
works.  but not for multiline.  see edit of original question above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read about [anchors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s48y7b93%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to understand why your pattern didn't match
   your single line input with text before and/or after the Schema
   element.
2. Read about the . (dot) [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to understand why patterns containing ".*" fail for multi-line input.
3. Read about (non-)greedy matching [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/193ztwkw%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to understand @Robert's answer better.
4. Use the character class [\s\S] (whitespace or non-whitespace = everything) to match across lines.

In code:

```
Option Explicit

Const csFSpec = "..\data\29976432.xml"

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sAll : sAll     = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec).ReadAll()
WScript.Echo sAll
WScript.Echo "----------------"
Dim re   : Set re   = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "<Schema[\S\s]*</Schema>"
WScript.Echo re.Replace(sAll, "|replaced|")
```

output:

```
cscript 29976432.vbs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <GRS_MESSAGES>
  <RESPONSE_FORMAT_CODE>XML</RESPONSE_FORMAT_CODE>
  <RESPONSE_CONTENT_CODE>FAIL</RESPONSE_CONTENT_CODE>
  <Schema name="Schema1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
   <ElementType name="C" content="empty" model="closed">
    <AttributeType name="Tag" dt:type="i4"/>
    <WhatEver/>
   </ElementType>
  </Schema>
 </GRS_MESSAGES>


----------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <GRS_MESSAGES>
  <RESPONSE_FORMAT_CODE>XML</RESPONSE_FORMAT_CODE>
  <RESPONSE_CONTENT_CODE>FAIL</RESPONSE_CONTENT_CODE>
  |replaced|
 </GRS_MESSAGES>
```

Comment: I do appreciate the links and thought put into this.  really all I needed was the pattern you provided though <Schema[\S\s]*</Schema>

unfortunately, that won't work in my scenario either, it won't find the multiline schema.  the way you have it coded is a bit different from me, but I will try a standalone solution tomorrow thanks.